# Get users based on status

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]

I have this data in the attached image, some users have a pharmacist category only and some users have a doctor and pharmacist category, and some users have a doctor category only.
how I can get the user who has Doctor Category only on one row??

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for existence of a status other than doctor.

```
select distinct tw_userid
from users
where not exists(select 1 from users t1 where t1.tw_userid = t.tw_userid and category_status <> 'Doctor Category')
```

BTW is it really useful to include Category in Doctor Category?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done using below query:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table users(
   tw_userId INT ,
   category_Status VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

insert into users
values
(8,'Doctor Category'),
(8,'Doctor Category'),
(8,'Doctor Category'),
(2836,'pharmacist Category'),
(2836,'pharmacist Category'),
(13174,'Doctor Category');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT tw_userId, COUNT(*) as total
, COUNT(CASE WHEN category_status = 'Doctor Category' THEN 1 END) as doctor_total FROM users
group by tw_userId 
HAVING total = doctor_total;
```

| tw_userId | total | doctor_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 3 | 3 |
| 13174 | 1 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nTQihha2qt4biBdM7XbT6s/0)

Comment: DBfiddle is empty?

Comment: and total = 1 - excludes userid = 8 OP has this ticked so should be included

Comment: @P.Salmon, sorry did not notice that earlier. thanks. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout use of exists keyword, all you need to search data with Doctor Category and a not exists clause for any other category.

something like below

```
select * from users u1 where category_status = 'Doctor_Category'
and not exists (select 1 from users u2 where u1.tw_userid = u2.tw_userid and category_status<> 'Doctor_category');
```